# SP execution time is extremely slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-optimization

I created a stored procedure that calculates a financial spreading based on a linear self adjusting rule and it takes more than 2 minutes to finish the calculations.

The final value goes through multiple iterations in order to adjust and enhance it till finding the optimal optimized final value.
The parameters are the following:

```
@input1 = 100000
@input2 = 40
@input3 = 106833


BEGIN
DECLARE @X decimal(22,6) = 0
DECLARE @Y decimal(22,6) = 0.001 
DECLARE @Z decimal(22,6)
DECLARE @r decimal(22,6)
DECLARE @v decimal(22,6) 

SET @v = POWER(1/(1+ (@Y/12)), @input2)
    SET @r = ((@Y/@input2) * input1) / (1-@v) 
    IF (@r < @input3)
        SET @Z = @Y + ABS((@X - @Y)/2)
    ELSE
        SET @Z = @Y - ABS((@X - @Y) /2)

    SET @X = @Y
    SET @Y = @Z 


WHILE (ABS(@r - @input3) > 0.001)
BEGIN
SET @v = POWER(1/(1+ (@Y/12)), @input2)
    SET @r = ((@Y/@input2) * @input1) / (1-@v) 
    IF (@r < @input3)
         SET @Z = @Y + ABS((@X - @Y)/2)
    ELSE
         SET @Z = @Y - ABS((@X - @Y) /2)
    SET @X = @Y
    IF @Y = @Z
    BREAK
    SET @Y = @Z
END

RETURN (CAST(@Y AS decimal(22,6)) * 100)



END
```

run time = 2 mins and 20 seconds

Comment: What parameter values do you call this stored procedure with?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu input1 = 100000
input2 = 40
input3 = 106833

Comment: You have a `WHILE` loop in there, do you know how many loops does it actually need to execute to break? Without understanding what you are actually trying to do, we can't give you a good reason.

Comment: Why are you running this on your database? The stored procedure doesn't appear to access or manipulate any data. Most database engines are optimized for data access, not mathematical calculations.

Comment: @EzLo hundreds..

Comment: @NevilleKuyt because I need it for a DB project so I am kinda cuffed here :(

Comment: @HoussemTimoumi I'm counting the amount of iterations the while is doing and had to stop the process after 5 minutes of running because I don't know if it will be endless. So it's not hundreds, it's probably **hundreds of thousands**. The problem is your loop there.

Comment: @EzLo ran it again on SQL server 2019. execution time is 2m45s and the number of iterations is 42,731,209. DO you have any suggestions?

Comment: Not without knowing what the loop is trying to achieve. However, this is more of an algorithmic problem rather than SQL one. You won't be able to speed up these kind of calculations on SQL Server, since they are very simple operations. What you can try to do is to change the algorithm itself to compute less operations.

Comment: @EzLo I don't think I can come up with a better algorithm but I'll try my best

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to your stored procedure written in TSQL might be a SQL CLR function written in C#. You have to use Visual Studio and create a Database Project.

```
    public static decimal ConvertTo6(double d)
    {
        return Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(d), 6, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    }

    public static decimal ConvertTo6(decimal d)
    {
        return Math.Round(d, 6, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    }


    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    [return: SqlFacet(Precision = 22, Scale = 6)]
    public static SqlDecimal CalcFinancialSpreading(int input1 = 100000, int input2 = 40, int input3 = 106833)
    {
        decimal x = 0.000000m;
        decimal y = 0.001000m;
        decimal z;
        decimal r;
        decimal v;

        v = ConvertTo6(Math.Pow(1 / (1 + (Convert.ToDouble(y) / 12d)), input2));

        r = ConvertTo6(((y / input2) * input1) / (1 - v));

        if (r < input3)
        {
            z = y + Math.Abs((x - y) / 2);
            z = ConvertTo6(z);
        }
        else
        {
            z = y - Math.Abs((x - y) / 2);
            z = ConvertTo6(z);
        }

        x = y;
        y = z;

        while (Math.Abs(r - input3) > 0.001m)
        {
            v = ConvertTo6((Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(1 / (1 + (y / 12))), Convert.ToDouble(input2))));

            r = ((y / input2) * input1) / (1 - v);
            r = ConvertTo6(r);

            if (r < input3)
            {
                z = y + Math.Abs((x - y) / 2);
                z = ConvertTo6(z);
            }
            else
            {
                z = y - Math.Abs((x - y) / 2);
                z = ConvertTo6(z);
            }
            x = y;
            if (y == z) break;
            y = z;
        }

        decimal result = y * 100;

        return new SqlDecimal(result);
    }
```

Executed as C# code the result is received in 45 seconds on my machine vs. TSQL in 1 Min 56 seconds.

Kudos to @wikiCan by answering [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58729607/converting-tsql-code-to-c-sharp-data-type-problem)...

Comment: Not that it would matter, but the result of his code, for the same parameters in SQL, is: 4273.320000

Comment: You're right, just saw it... seems to be a datatype conversion problem... I'll check it out

Comment: That may be an option! Thanks a bunch!