# Converting TSQL code to C# data type problem

Tags: c#, t-sql, sqlclr

I was trying to answer this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58726514/sp-execution-time-is-extremely-slow)..

Given the following TSQL code

```
DECLARE @input1 INT = 100000
DECLARE @input2 INT = 40
DECLARE @input3 INT = 106833

DECLARE @X decimal(22,6) = 0
DECLARE @Y decimal(22,6) = 0.001 
DECLARE @Z decimal(22,6)
DECLARE @r decimal(22,6)
DECLARE @v decimal(22,6) 

SET @v = POWER(1/(1+ (@Y/12)), @input2)
    SET @r = ((@Y/@input2) * @input1) / (1-@v) 
    IF (@r < @input3)
        SET @Z = @Y + ABS((@X - @Y)/2)
    ELSE
        SET @Z = @Y - ABS((@X - @Y) /2)

    SET @X = @Y
    SET @Y = @Z 


WHILE (ABS(@r - @input3) > 0.001)
BEGIN
SET @v = POWER(1/(1+ (@Y/12)), @input2)
    SET @r = ((@Y/@input2) * @input1) / (1-@v) 
    IF (@r < @input3)
         SET @Z = @Y + ABS((@X - @Y)/2)
    ELSE
         SET @Z = @Y - ABS((@X - @Y) /2)
    SET @X = @Y
    IF @Y = @Z
    BREAK
    SET @Y = @Z
END

SELECT (CAST(@Y AS decimal(22,6)) * 100)
```

I tried to convert it to C#

```
            decimal input1 = 100000m;
            decimal input2 = 40m;
            decimal input3 = 106833m;

            decimal x = 0m;
            decimal y = 0.001m;
            decimal z;
            decimal r;
            decimal v;

            v = (decimal)(Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(1m / (1m + (y / 12m))), Convert.ToDouble(input2)));

            r = ((y / input2) * input1) / (1 - v);

            if (r<input3)
            {
                z = y + Math.Abs((x - y) / 2);
            }
            else
            {
                z = y - Math.Abs((x - y) / 2);
            }

            x = y;
            y = z;

            while (Math.Abs(r - input3) > 0.001m)
            {
                v = (decimal)(Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(1 / (1 + (y / 12))), Convert.ToDouble(input2)));

                r = ((y / input2) * input1) / (1 - v);

                if (r<input3)
                {
                    z = y + Math.Abs((x - y) / 2);
                }
                else
                {
                    z = y - Math.Abs((x - y) / 2);
                }
                x = y;
                if (y==z) break;
                y = z;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(y*100);
```

But the results are different.

The TSQL returns 4273.320000 whereas the C# code returns 0,1999999999999999999999998900.
Furthermore if i put the exact same C# code inside a SqlFunction (CLR function) via

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
public static decimal CalcFinancialSpreading(decimal input1 = 100000, decimal input2 = 40, decimal input3 = 106833)
```

it returns 0

Does anybody spot the error?

Comment: I didn't go over the entire code, but the first free declares are ints in TSQL and decimal in c#, so here's one thing that might effect the outcome.

Comment: T-SQL's `POWER` performs particularly poorly if you let it loose on `DECIMAL` types, because the result always has maximum precision (38), which can easily cut into the scale when used in subsequent calculations. (Up until recently, this wasn't even documented.) If you then put this in a *loop*, the inaccuracies mount. Use `FLOAT` for these calculations, so they're on par with what C# does. (As a bonus, the calculation will actually finish in a reasonable time.) Making the calculation "correct" (i.e. avoiding compounding rounding problems in all cases) is another matter, in both cases.

Comment: Worth noting also is that C#'s `decimal` and T-SQL's `DECIMAL` don't have the same precision/scale limit, so even if you translated things "directly" to C# the results would likely still be different. For an "accurate" translation, you can use the `SqlDecimal` type, but this may well be as slow as the T-SQL original, and it would still be hard to tell if the calculation is then correct or not. Even so, it's an option. The current mixture of `decimal` and `double` is the worst of both worlds, sort of.

Comment: Thanks Zohar and Jeroen for your input - using the float datatype gave the same result - but info was useful though. The posted answer works.

Answer (score 2):

Your Solution it is. So answer is c# decimal precision is different than SQL, in SQL you are use 6 precision digit. So always set your number same like this (example) you can write your own helper converter class. :

```
public static decimal ConvertTo6(double d)
    {
        return Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(d), 6, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    }

    public static decimal ConvertTo6(decimal d)
    {
        return Math.Round(d, 6, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int input1 = 100000;
        int input2 = 40;
        int input3 = 106833;


        decimal x = 0.000000m;
        decimal y = 0.001000m;
        decimal z;
        decimal r;
        decimal v;

        v = ConvertTo6(Pow(1 / (1 + (Convert.ToDouble(y) / 12d)), input2));

        r = ConvertTo6(((y / input2) * input1) / (1 - v));


        if (r < input3)
        {
            z = y + Math.Abs((x - y) / 2);
            z = ConvertTo6(z);
        }
        else
        {
            z = y - Math.Abs((x - y) / 2);
            z = ConvertTo6(z);
        }

        x = y;
        y = z;

        while (Math.Abs(r - input3) > 0.001m)
        {
            v = ConvertTo6((Math.Pow(Convert.ToDouble(1 / (1 + (y / 12))), Convert.ToDouble(input2))));

            r = ((y / input2) * input1) / (1 - v);
            r = ConvertTo6(r);

            if (r < input3)
            {
                z = y + Math.Abs((x - y) / 2);
                z = ConvertTo6(z);
            }
            else
            {
                z = y - Math.Abs((x - y) / 2);
                z = ConvertTo6(z);
            }
            x = y;
            if (y == z) break;
            y = z;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(y * 100);

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you - it gives the expected result!

Comment: Given that it produces "the expected result" by continuously rounding results, that almost certainly demonstrates that the result is incorrect, or at the very least that there's a much more appropriate implementation of the algorithm... even though that's another problem entirely.